# Merging Templatefield vs Boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, merge

I have this row field which contain same value from the previous row. I can merge it with using boundField, but when i change it to templateField, the last row in my code didn't work like i wanted to. So i compare it using bound field (change the last row into boundfield), and it worked. The reason i used templatefield is because i wanted to use the linkbutton commandArgument, So it can pass the data selected into another page using session. So my question is, why merging not working so well with template field? But its work well with bound field? I still want to use the template field because of link button. But if someone can give me an example to use bound field with a link, i'm open to use it.

Here is my aspx code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewApproval" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AllowPaging="true"       
    Width="100%" OnDataBound="OnDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Data Found">

     <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNo" runat="server"
                    Text = '<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'> </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_ID" HeaderText="Emp ID"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_NAME" HeaderText="Emp Name"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="POSITION_DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Position"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="SECTION_DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Section"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="PROPOSED_TOPIC" HeaderText="Topic"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="METHOD_DEV_NAME" HeaderText="Method of Development"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ESTIMATE_COST" HeaderText="Cost Estimation(USD)" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ROD_DESC" HeaderText="Reason of Dev"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="SCHEDULE_PLAN" HeaderText="Schedule Plan"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ILP_CODE" HeaderText = "CODE" />

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CODE">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAction" runat="server"
                CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ILP_CODE")%>'                   
                Text = '<%# Bind("ILP_CODE")%>' OnClick = "ActionApproval"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack & Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }



    private void BindData()
    {
        String magicNumber = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies[Constant.CookiesEmployeeId].Value);
        decimal nextAppEmpId = decimal.Parse(magicNumber);
        GridViewApproval.DataSource = (nextAppEmpId.Equals("null") || nextAppEmpId == 0) ? apDetail.GetIlpProcessPosition() : apEntity.getIlpProcessPositionNextEmpId(nextAppEmpId);

        GridViewApproval.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ActionApproval(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton linkAction = (LinkButton)sender;
        Session["ILP_CODE"] = linkAction.CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("~/Web/ILP/ApprovalListDetail.aspx");
    }

    protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = GridViewApproval.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridViewApproval.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridViewApproval.Rows[i - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j != 0)
                {
                if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
                {
                    if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                        }
                        row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                }

            }
        }

        string ilpCode = null, ilpCodeSave = null;

        for (int count = 0; count < GridViewApproval.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            ilpCode = GridViewApproval.Rows[count].Cells[10].Text;
            if (!ilpCode.Equals(ilpCodeSave))
            {
                //GridViewApproval.Rows[count].Cells[10].Text = "Details";
            }
            ilpCodeSave = GridViewApproval.Rows[count].Cells[10].Text;

        }
    }
```

And here is the image when i compile
[image: BoundVSTemplate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i can do:
Enjoy

```
//looping for boundfield
    for (int i = GridViewApproval.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridViewApproval.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridViewApproval.Rows[i - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count & j != 5; j++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
                {
                    if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                        }
                        row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Looping for TemplateField
        for (int i = GridViewApproval.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridViewApproval.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridViewApproval.Rows[i - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                //Define what index on your template field cell that contain same value
                if (((LinkButton)row.Cells[9].FindControl("linkAction")).Text == ((LinkButton)previousRow.Cells[9].FindControl("linkAction")).Text)
                {
                    if (previousRow.Cells[9].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[9].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[9].RowSpan += 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[9].RowSpan = row.Cells[9].RowSpan + 1;
                        }
                        row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //This is to redefine again.
        for (int count = 0; count < GridViewApproval.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            LinkButton lblprojectTest = GridViewApproval.Rows[count].Cells[9].FindControl("linkAction") as LinkButton;
            lblprojectTest.Text = "Details";
        }
```

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee (ID)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("emp_fullname")+ " " +"("+ Eval("emp_id") +")"%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
i have to merge this beacuse of multiple name n id